# copy of list modifies original list python

Tags: python, list, copy

I am trying to make a game that implements a pruned a-b minimax game tree search for tic-tac-toe (Xs and Os, knots and crosses, etc). However, I am not there yet. I am currently writing the code to create the tic-tac-toe board and assign points to the board.
This is the code for the tic-tac-toe boards - it uses + and - rather than X and O for now so that I can test my minimax code intuitively.

```
class Tictactoe:
__game = [[0, 0, 0] for i in range(0, 3)]

def print(self):
    for i in range(0, 3):
        for j in self.__game[i]:
            print(j, end=" ")
        print()

def playMove(self, max, i, j):
    if max:
        self.__game[i][j] = '+'
    else:
        self.__game[i][j] = '-'

def testMove(self, max, i, j):
    temp = list(self.__game)
    if max:
        temp[i][j] = '+'
    else:
        temp[i][j] = '-'
    return temp

def getState(self):
    return list(self.__game)

def getValue(self, symbol, game):
    diag1 = True
    diag2 = True
    for i in range(0, 3):
        column = True
        row = True
        for j in range(0, 3):
            row &= game[i][j] == symbol
            column &= game[j][i] == symbol
            if i==j:
                diag1 &= game[i][j] == symbol
                diag2 &= game[i][2-j] == symbol
    if row or column or diag1 or diag2:
        return 1
    return 0
```

The program that uses Tictactoe is as follows:

```
from tictactoe import Tictactoe

t = Tictactoe()

def main():
    global t
    t.playMove(True,0,2)
    t.playMove(True,1,1)
    t.playMove(True,2,2)

    t.print()
    print(t.getValue('+',t.getState()))
    print(t.getValue('-',t.getState()))
    print(t.getValue('+',t.testMove(True,2,0)))
    t.print()

main()
```

Ignore form for now - I'm just trying to get the Tictactoe methods working. When running the code, I get this:

```
0 0 + 
0 + 0 
0 0 + 
0
0
1
0 0 + 
0 + 0 
+ 0 +
```

My problem is that I would like to be able to get the tentative score of a board after making a particular move - This is the line

```
(t.getValue('+',t.testMove(True,2,0))
```

Which should be making a copy of the game board to test the move on.

```
def testMove(self, max, i, j):
    temp = list(self.__game)
    if max:
        temp[i][j] = '+'
    else:
        temp[i][j] = '-'
    return temp
```

However, as you can see, my print method only prints the ACTUAL game board - which should not be affected by testing a move on the copy of the board. However, we can see that testing adding a point at (2,2) actually adds that point to the game. If anyone can see exactly what is happening here that would be great.

Comment: You have a nested list, and `list` only makes a *shallow copy*. You need a deep copy.

Comment: THANK YOU! This is what i needed.